# Getting a __NSArray0 from a JWT

Tags: arrays, swift, jwt, token

I have an api that creates a JWT for a logged in user and when I look at the decoded version of the token on jwt.io I get what I expect.

It shows that the data property is `[]` and it holds the users data when a user is logged in.

Now I am trying to decode this into swift for my iOS app, but the data in the data property comes back as:

```
(
)
```

and the type for this is `__NSArray0`

I can't loop through it or anything - what is a `__NSArray0` and how would decode the token properly?

Comment: `__NSArray0` means a `NSArray` which is specific because it has zero element. It's immutable and optmized, that's why it doesn't say `NSArray`. It's an internal class. You can cast is as `[Any]`, or `[Something]`  where `Something` is usually the class of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`__NSArray0`:

`__NSArray` means it's an `NSArray` object. It's the "old Objective-C immutable Array type". That's what gives you after decoding an JSON Array with `(NS)JSONSerialization` if you don't cast it into a Swift Array.

The `0` at the end is to say it's a specific `NSArray`, it's an `NSArray` empty, with no object. Why using that? Because in reality, it's a internal version of `NSArray` that is optimized for zero elements. So don't mind about it.

Since you have a `NSArray`, typical print of it, is:

```
(
)
```

So just cast it as an `Array` how its supposed type when non-empty to iterate. If you know it's an array of String, cast is as `[String]` and iterate over it.

It's the OpenStep format. Did you ever tried to read a PBXCodeProj?
Like `more yourApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` It's there, you see how are printed `NSDictionary`, `NSArray` etc in that Format + comments.

In JSON, it's `[]` to show it's an Array, but in Objective-C the print is different.

Want to reproduce it?

```
let emptyNSArray = NSArray()
print("emptyNSArray:\n\(emptyNSArray)")
let castedEmptyAsArray = emptyNSArray as [AnyObject]
print("castedEmptyAsArray:\n\(castedEmptyAsArray)")

let nsArray = NSArray(array: ["Hello", "World", "!"])
print("nsArray:\n\(nsArray)")
let castedAsArray = nsArray as [AnyObject]
print("castedAsArray:\n\(castedAsArray)")

let emptyArrayJSON = Data("[]".utf8)
let decodedEmptyArrayDefault = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: emptyArrayJSON)
print("decodedEmptyArrayDefault:\n\(decodedEmptyArrayDefault)") //If you don't cast, it's by default a NSArray
let decodedEmptyArrayCasted = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: emptyArrayJSON) as! [AnyObject]
print("decodedEmptyArrayCasted:\n\(decodedEmptyArrayCasted)")
```

Output:

```
$>emptyNSArray:
(
)
$>castedEmptyAsArray:
[]
$>nsArray:
(
    Hello,
    World,
    "!"
)
$>castedAsArray:
[Hello, World, !]
$>decodedEmptyArrayDefault:
(
)
$>decodedEmptyArrayCasted:
[]
```